# How do I Intentionally cause a database validation error on insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to cause a database validation error when inserting into (or editing) the database to test the try/catch

C# is too smart and catches my type casting errors.

Comment: insert into some not existant table ? will that work

Comment: Or a null value into a non-nullable column, or break a foreign key constraint, or try to put (eg) 11 characters into a varchar(10) column.

Comment: C# catches the null value into non-nullable fields

Comment: or insert duplicate key values ...this is not that difficult to do ..I would read up more on Database Inserts and Constraints and try to understand them

Comment: "C# catches the null value into non-nullable fields". That depends on what your C# code is, you have not included any code in your question.

Comment: c# does not catches null values by default, that is up to you so just leave out that code

Comment: Stopping Sql Server instance will certainly work.

Comment: just delete a record from a master table that still has records in its detail table

Comment: I like the idea of stopping the SQL service... However I don't have the access to do so on this server.

Comment: unplug your network cable that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks guys for all the suggestions. Since I can't mark comments as the answer and it was discussed in the single answer, I have marked that as answered.

Comment: It appears that there is a lot of arrogance on this site. As a relatively new C# developer, I am annoyed that several people marked this question down for what I assume is the simplicity of the topic. I asked what turned out to be a very simple question and people have marked it down? It helped me with my situation and people don't like that? I am disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting a value that doesn't fit into a column (a string 10 characters long in a varchar(2)),

reference a foreign key that does not exist,

a null value in a column that doesn't accept nulls,

try connecting to the database with the wrong password/user combination.

Without any sql/c# code it's hard to know how you have things setup

**EDIT- answer in comments:**
"do you have any identity fields? try inserting a value that already exists into that column"

Comment: C# is smart enough to catch the intentional null value into a non-null field.

Comment: How are you inserting the data? can you provide any code?

Comment: Using perhaps, the entity framework?

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework is being used.

I tried null on a datetime field and C# caught it, Won't work on Int either... Next I will try it on a string field.

Comment: do you have any identity fields? try inserting a value that already exists into that column

Comment: Thanks @SchwartzBrian. It didn't cross my mind to insert an existing ID to cause the error.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and indicate the answer is in the comments?